# useImmer with Image: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immer.js

I am trying to cache Images for later rendering on canvas using `drawImage`.

So I defined type for cache:

```js
type Cache = {
  image: Record<string, HTMLImageElement>,
};

const initialCache = {
  image: {},
};
```

In parent component I am using it with `useImmer`:

```js
function Component() {
  const [cache, setCache] = useImmer(initialCache);

  return <Child cache={cache} setCache={setCache} />
}
```

Finally in child component I try to get (or set) it inside `useEffect` with async IIFE:

```js
function Child(props: { cache: Cache, setCache: Updater<Cache> }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const imageKey = "forDemonstrationPurposes";
      const maybeImg = props.cache.image[imageKey];

      let img = maybeImg;

      if (!img) {
        img = new Image();

        img.src = "Some base64 string";

        props.setCache((d) => {
          d.image[imageKey] = img; // ERROR!
        });
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

At place marked `ERROR!` I get in vscode:

`Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | WritableDraft<ProcessingInstruction> | null'.`

While browser screams at me with very long error message:

```
Type 'HTMLImageElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLImageElement>'.
  Types of property 'offsetParent' are incompatible.
    Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | null'.
      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element>'.
        Types of property 'attributes' are incompatible.
          Type 'NamedNodeMap' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<NamedNodeMap>'.
            'number' index signatures are incompatible.
              Type 'Attr' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Attr>'.
                The types of 'ownerDocument.anchors' are incompatible between these types.
                  Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLAnchorElement>>'.
                    'number' index signatures are incompatible.
                      Type 'HTMLAnchorElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
                        Types of property 'shadowRoot' are incompatible.
                          Type 'ShadowRoot | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ShadowRoot> | null'.
                            Type 'ShadowRoot' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ShadowRoot>'.
                              Types of property 'childNodes' are incompatible.
                                Type 'NodeListOf<ChildNode>' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<NodeListOf<ChildNode>>'.
                                  'number' index signatures are incompatible.
                                    Type 'ChildNode' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ChildNode>'.
                                      Types of property 'parentElement' are incompatible.
                                        Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLElement> | null'.
                                          Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLElement>'.
                                            Types of property 'assignedSlot' are incompatible.
                                              Type 'HTMLSlotElement | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLSlotElement> | null'.
                                                Type 'HTMLSlotElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLSlotElement>'.
                                                  The types of 'style.parentRule' are incompatible between these types.
                                                    Type 'CSSRule | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSRule> | null'.
                                                      Type 'CSSRule' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSRule>'.
                                                        Types of property 'parentStyleSheet' are incompatible.
                                                          Type 'CSSStyleSheet | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSStyleSheet> | null'.
                                                            Type 'CSSStyleSheet' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSStyleSheet>'.
                                                              Types of property 'ownerNode' are incompatible.
                                                                Type 'Element | ProcessingInstruction | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | WritableDraft<ProcessingInstruction> | null'.
                                                                  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | WritableDraft<ProcessingInstruction> | null'.
    48 |             setCache((d) => {
    49 |               if (img) {
  > 50 |                 d.image[imageSrc] = img;
       |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    51 |               }
    52 |             });
    53 |           }
```

Intuitively I understand that error happens because not all attributes of Elements can be modified in ways that `useImmer` expects. So my question is, how to prevent this error, or alternatively, how to "tell" `useImmer` that I am not going to edit images, just get/set them?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Cast utilities](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/typescript#cast-utilities) documentation, we can use `castDraft`:

> Converts any immutable type to its mutable counterpart. This is just a cast and doesn't actually do anything.

```
import { castDraft } from 'immer';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Updater, useImmer } from 'use-immer';

type Cache = {
    image: Record<string, HTMLImageElement>;
};

const initialCache = {
    image: {},
};

function Child(props: { cache: Cache; setCache: Updater<Cache> }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const imageKey = 'forDemonstrationPurposes';
            const maybeImg = props.cache.image[imageKey];
            let img = maybeImg;
            if (!img) {
                img = new Image();
                img.src = 'Some base64 string';
                props.setCache((d) => {
                    d.image[imageKey] = castDraft(img);
                });
            }
        })();
    }, []);

    return null;
}

function Component() {
    const [cache, setCache] = useImmer(initialCache);
    return (
        <Child
            cache={cache}
            setCache={setCache}
        />
    );
}
```

package versions:

```json
"immer": "^10.0.2",
"use-immer": "^0.9.0"
```